# Filling above/below matplotlib line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to create a simple line plot. My plot is a simple time-series data set where I have time along the x-axis and the value of something I am measuring on the y-axis. y values can have postitive or negative values and I would like to fill in the area above and below my line with the color blue if the y-value is > 0 and red if the y values is < 0. Here's my plot:

[image]

As you can see, I can get the blue color to fill in correctly, but I can not get the red color to fill in properly. Here's the basic code I am using:

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', lw=1)
d = scipy.zeros(len(y))
ax.fill_between(xs,ys,where=ys>=d, color='blue')
ax.fill_between(xs,0,where=ys<=d, color='red')
```

How can I get the area from a positive y-value to the x-axis to be blue and the area from a negative y-value to the x-axis to be red? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe the last line in the code snippet should be `ax.fill_between(xs,ys,where=ys<=d, color='red')`, as you are now trying to fill the area between `y1=0` and `y2=0` (i.e. no area). The second argument (in this case `ys`) is passed to the `y1` parameter, and since `y2` has default value `0`, the method will fill the area _between_ the array you have specified for `y1` and the line y=0, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your suggestion partly worked. However, I still am not geting the proper color fill in cases where a point say, (10, 10) is connected to another point that crosses the x-axis, say (11, -10). Here's what the plot looks like: http://postimg.org/image/u329jhlob/

Comment: Ah, I figured that was what you wanted, seeing how you said the blue fill on the figure above was correct. This should be an easy fix: `ax.fill_between(xs,ys,where=ys<=d, interpolate=True, color='red')`. The `interpolate` parameter makes the function interpolate to find the intersection between the `y1` and `y2` arrays, as to get a "smoother" plot.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The code snippet you provided should be corrected as follows:

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', lw=1)
d = scipy.zeros(len(y))
ax.fill_between(xs, ys, where=ys>=d, interpolate=True, color='blue')
ax.fill_between(xs, ys, where=ys<=d, interpolate=True, color='red')
```

The [`fill_between`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) method takes at least two arguments `x` and `y1`, while it also has a parameter `y2` with default value 0. The method will fill the area between `y1` and `y2` for the specified `x`-values.

The reason why you didn't get any filling below the x-axis, is due to the fact that you had specified that the `fill_between` method should fill the area between `y1=0` and `y2=0`, i.e. *no* area. To make sure that the fill does not only appear on *explicit* x-values, specify that the method should interpolate `y1` as to find the intersections with `y2`, which is done by specifying `interpolate=True` in the method call.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! It also works if you skip the second line ´d = ...´ and replace the variable ´d´ by ´0´ in the third and forth line.

Comment: @TomPohl Thanks. Yes, I'm aware. The reason I kept the `d = ...` statement is that I don't make more changes to the OPs original code than necessary to make it functional. This is to make sure there is no confusion as to where the "mistake" was located.

Comment: I see. Just wanted to make sure that others using your solution know about the shortcut.

Comment: @sodd: can you make ax.fill appears in legend without drawing again the line, that is, draw the line and fill twice?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the keyword `interpolate=True`.

Comment: Ah, @nordev already wrote that in the comment above. I suggest you convert your comment to an answer so it can be properly upvoted.