# Plotting a curve with different background colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a curve after reading a data file. The background above the curve and below the curve should be different (say, red and green). This is like a phase diagram showing two different phases above and below a boundary line. Is it possible using matplotlib in python? My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Use numpy to load the data contained in the file
# 'data.txt' into a 2-D array called data
data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
# plot the first column as x, and second column as y
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
pl.plot(x,y, '-r')
pl.xlabel('x')
pl.ylabel('y')
pl.show()
```

The 'data.txt' file contains :

```
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
```

So it should plot a parabola.

There is a possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917919/filling-above-below-matplotlib-line-plot). However, that doesn't seem to work in my case.

Also I would like enter texts in the middle of the differently colored patches.

So my plot should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using matplotlib's fill_between. 
You can fill below the line simply with `plt.fill_between(x,y,color="whatever")`. To be more complete, you can set the lower bound of the fill with `plt.fill_between(x,0,y,color="whatever")`

To fill the whole area above the curve, you can use `plt.fill_between(x,y,plt.ylim()[1],color="whatever")`

Here is some demo code that works to fill both above and below the curve:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,9,10)
y = x ** 2
plt.plot(x,y,"b-")
plt.fill_between(x,y,color="red")
maxy = plt.ylim()[1]
plt.fill_between(x,y,maxy,color="green")
plt.show()
```

You can set x and y however you want.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: You can add text with matplotlib's text.
You need to specify the coordinates, but you could do something like

```
xtextplace = x[7]
ytextplace = y[7] / 2
plt.text(xtextplace,ytextplace,"Some Text")
```

I'd do something like:

```
xcoord = x[int((x.size/3)*2)]
ycoord = y[int((x.size/3)*2)] / 2
plt.text(xcoord,ycoord,"Text")
```

This would make the text appear 2/3 of the way along the x-axis and 1/2 way up under the curve at that point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have updated my question a bit. If I swap the colors, i.e. `plt.fill_between(x,y,color="green")` and `plt.fill_between(x,y,maxy,color="red")` , then I get my desired result. However, what does  `maxy = plt.ylim( )[1] ` imply?

Comment: @hbaromega plt.ylim() returns an list with the minimum value on the y-axis and the maximum value on the y-axis. `maxy = plt.ylim()[1]` simply extracts the second value of the list, which is the maximum y-value currently on the  plot (in this case, 90). That way, you don't need to guess as to what is the highest y-value you should fill up to.

Comment: @progmman so isn't it that `maxy = plt.ylim()[1]`  will only work for a monotonically increasing function?

Comment: @hbaromenga Nope. I phrased it wrong.`plt.ylim()` returns the current bounds of the y-axis, not the function plotted. This means that it can be used independent of the function on the plot.

Comment: thanks a lot. That means the maximum limit or range. Then it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I did some corrections to your code. The below code works fine(with the same "data.txt")

Python3 version:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.loadtxt('data.txt')
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]
(ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax2.fill_between(x, y, facecolor='green')
ax2.fill_between(x, y, plt.ylim()[1], facecolor='red')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. You've here used two subplots. However, if I use `color` instead of `facecolor`, the code still works though the boundary line between red and green doesn't remain that thick. Can you explain why?