# How to fill above and below a straight line in python's matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am wondering how to fill the area above and below a straight line in matplotlib. For example, I have the following code for a plot

```
ax.axhline(y=0,color='black',linestyle='--')
```

I am wondering how to fill the area above that line green, and below it red. I checked out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917919/filling-above-below-matplotlib-line-plot) but a lineplot is different than just a straight line. I am familiar with `.fill_between()` but not sure how to utilize it in this scenario, since it takes an x and y argument. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to get the x axis range in which you want to plot and then just use `plt.fill_between`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_val = 2
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,1,10)
plt.axhline(y=y_val)
plt.fill_between(x,0, y_val)
plt.fill_between(x, y_val, 4, color='r')
plt.show()
```

This image shows you the example
[image]

And if you do not know the limits, then probably use `plt.gca().get_ylim()` and `plt.gca().get_xlim()` to get the x and y range

In that case it will be modified to

```py
y_val = 0.5
import numpy as np
x2 = plt.gca().get_xlim()
print (x2)
y2 = plt.gca().get_ylim()

plt.axhline(y=y_val)
plt.fill_between(x2,y2[0], y_val)
plt.fill_between(x2, y_val, y2[1], color='r')
print (y2[0])
plt.show()
```