Bar chart with slanted lines instead of horizontal lines
I wish to display a barchart over a time series canvas, where the bars have width that match the duration and where the edges connect the first value with the last value. In other words, how could I have slanted bars at the top to match the data?
I know how to make barcharts using either the last value (example 1) or the first value (example 2), but what I'm looking for are polygons that would follow the black line shown.
Example 1

Example 2

Code:
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import Timestamp
    import datetime
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np  # np.nan

    dd = {'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Start': {0: Timestamp('1800-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1850-01-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1950-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'End': {0: Timestamp('1849-12-31 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1949-12-31 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1979-12-31 00:00:00')}, 'Team': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Red'}, 'Duration': {0: 50*365-1, 1: 100*365-1, 2: 30*365-1}, 'First': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 8}, 'Last': {0: 10, 1: 8, 2: 12}}
    d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd)
    d.dtypes
    d

    # set up colors for team
    colors = {'Red': '#E81B23', 'Blue': '#00AEF3'}

    # reshape data to get a single Date | is there a better way?
    def reshape(data):
            d1 = data[['Start', 'Name', 'Team', 'Duration', 'First']].rename(columns={'Start': 'Date', 'First': 'value'})
            d2 = data[['End', 'Name', 'Team', 'Duration', 'Last']].rename(columns={'End': 'Date', 'Last': 'value'})
            return pd.concat([d1, d2]).sort_values(by='Date').reset_index(drop=True)
    df = reshape(d)
    df.dtypes
    df

    plt.plot(df['Date'], df['value'], color='black')
    plt.bar(d['Start'], height=d['Last'], align='edge', 
            width=list(+d['Duration']), 
            edgecolor='white', linewidth=2,
            color=[colors[key] for key in d['Team']])
    plt.show()

    plt.plot(df['Date'], df['value'], color='black')
    plt.bar(d['End'], height=d['First'], align='edge', 
            width=list(-d['Duration']), 
            edgecolor='white', linewidth=2,
            color=[colors[key] for key in d['Team']])
    plt.show()
            


It looks like you just want a line chart with the space underneath coloured in? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917919/filling-above-below-matplotlib-line-plot

Yes, that sounds right! But with the coloring based on the 'Team' variable. Let me read the post you link to.

Off-topic, but I'm really happy to see a well written question on SO nowadays

Thanks @alko. The large majority of the questions I plan to post on SO get resolved as I prepare a minimum example, so the extra effort is definitely worthwhile! :-)

You can use Matplotlibs Axes.fill_between
to generate these types of charts. Importantly this will accurately represent the
gap between your rows where they exist, whereas the approach with the bars will
make that gap appear to be wider than they truly are unless you set the edgewidth
of the bars to 0.
Additionally, for your data transformation this is a pandas.lreshape
which is similar to performing multiple melts operations at the same time.
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dd = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name':     ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Start':    pd.to_datetime(['1800-01-01', '1850-01-01', '1950-01-01']),
    'End':      pd.to_datetime(['1849-12-31', '1949-12-31', '1979-12-31']),
    'Team':     ['Red', 'Blue', 'Red'],
    'Duration': [50*365-1, 100*365-1, 30*365-1],
    'First':    [5, 10, 8],
    'Last':     [10, 8, 12]
})
df = (
    pd.lreshape(dd, groups={'Date': ['Start', 'End'], 'Value': ['First', 'Last']})
    .sort_values('Date')
)
colors = {'Red': '#E81B23', 'Blue': '#00AEF3'}


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for team in df['Team'].unique():
    ax.fill_between(
        df['Date'],
        df['Value'],
        where=(df['Team'] == team),
        color=colors[team],
        linewidth=0,
    )
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)

plt.show()



Great answer, thanks Cameron. Let me play around with the code before selecting an answer! I love pd.lreshape, I didn't know about it (I only know pd.merge, pd.join, pd.concat, and pd.groupby().agg(), so great one to know! I appended .reindex(['Date', 'Name', 'Team', 'Value'], axis=1) to get a specific order and remove the Duration column as it is no longer needed. Quick question: I know df.to_dict() to copy dataframes, and also df.to_clipboard() to print, but I see you have df=pd.DataFrame({...}), did you do that "by hand" or do you know a convenient way? Thanks again!

Glad pd.lreshape is new and handy to you! For "sharing" copy/pasteable versions of a DataFrame, you can do df.to_dict('list') to get a view similar to the one I used as the input data. Then use pd.DataFrame to read those values back in. There are many other formats you can receive from the to_dict method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

I ended up making these:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/M6zgKawp.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/cwGRTUgY.png

I had to deal with a couple of minor annoyances: (1) In my data, consecutive Start and End date were the same, which messed up the index when using pd.lreshape; could probably have been fixed by dealing with seconds, but I went full sledgehammer mode with d['End'] = d['End'] - pd.Timedelta(1, unit='D'); (2) when the Start/End days did not coincide with the actual data, I had interpolated, with the result that there was a small jump at the transition date, caused by using first day of month vs. last day of month; fixed it with an ugly hack d.loc[d.index > 0, 'First'] = d1[col].shift(+1).

Anyways writing this here for my future self more than anything! Thanks again Cameron. Great answer.

I would take the following approach:

Make a regular bar plot using, for each bar, the maximum extent of its two height values (this to get the correct y axis limits set automatically).
Convert all bars of the bar plot, which are matplotlib.patches.Rectangle instances, to matplotlib.patches.Polygon instances, adjust the necessary corners and copy over all other attributes (color, line width, etc.).
In the plot, replace the rectangle bars with the polygon bars.

The function polybar() in the following code achieves this (it also allows for **kwargs to be passed through to plt.bar():
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def polybar(x, y_left, y_right, **kwargs):
    
    def poly_from(rect, yl, yr):
        (x, y), w = rect.get_xy(), rect.get_width()
        p = Polygon([(x, y), (x + w, y), (x + w, yr), (x, yl)], closed=True)
        p.update_from(rect)  # Copy over properties from rectangle
        return p
    
    ax = plt.gca()
    # Create regular bar plot with maximum y extent
    height = np.where(np.abs(y_left) > np.abs(y_right), y_left, y_right)
    bars = ax.bar(x, height, **kwargs)
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    # Convert rectangle bars to polygon bars
    polys = [poly_from(*blr) for blr in zip(bars, y_left, y_right)]
    # Replace rectangle bars with polygon bars
    for bar in bars:
        bar.remove()
    for poly in polys:
        ax.add_patch(poly)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim)

In your own code, you could use this as follows:
# TODO: Prepend imports and `polybar()` from above here

import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

dd = {'Name': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'}, 'Start': {0: Timestamp('1800-01-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1850-01-01 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1950-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'End': {0: Timestamp('1849-12-31 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('1949-12-31 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('1979-12-31 00:00:00')}, 'Team': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Red'}, 'Duration': {0: 50*365-1, 1: 100*365-1, 2: 30*365-1}, 'First': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 8}, 'Last': {0: 10, 1: 8, 2: 12}}
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd)
colors = {'Red': '#E81B23', 'Blue': '#00AEF3'}
def reshape(data):
        d1 = data[['Start', 'Name', 'Team', 'Duration', 'First']].rename(columns={'Start': 'Date', 'First': 'value'})
        d2 = data[['End', 'Name', 'Team', 'Duration', 'Last']].rename(columns={'End': 'Date', 'Last': 'value'})
        return pd.concat([d1, d2]).sort_values(by='Date').reset_index(drop=True)
df = reshape(d)

polybar(d['Start'], d['First'], d['Last'], align='edge', 
        width=list(+d['Duration']), 
        edgecolor='white', linewidth=2,
        color=[colors[key] for key in d['Team']])
plt.show()

The result looks as follows:

Some edge cases are currently not covered. These are the ones that I am aware of:

The conversion assumes that the bottom values of the bar plot are all zeros. To handle other values, the rectangle-to-polygon conversion would need to be adjusted.
The setting of the y limits is not correct in the case that, for one and the same bar, y_left is the overall largest negative value and y_right is the overall largest positive value (or vice versa).
I did not test whether the code works with units.


Thanks @simon, this looks great! I appreciate the detailed explanations. I will experiment a little with your code before selecting an answer.

@PatrickT No worries! Choose whatever answer suits you best :)
